# Integer and Unicode values for characters?

Tags: java, character

Here is some code:

```
   private static final char low = 'a';
   private static final char high = 'z';
   private static final int arrayLength = high - low + 1;
```

I think arrayLength will be equal to 26, but I'm not sure. Is this correct? My second question is that what is the numerical value difference between 'a' and 'A'? When I used the getNumericValue() method in the Character class to test both characters:

```
  String element = "a";
  int x = Character.getNumericValue(element.charAt(0));
```

I tested both 'a' and 'A' and I got 10 both times. So, in general, I'm confused about the numerical values of chars. Please advise.

Comment: *"I think arrayLength will be equal to 26, but I'm not sure. Is this correct?"* Why exactly didn't you test ?

Comment: Character.getNumericValue is to be used for characters that represent numbers.

Answer (score 1):

[`Character.getNumericValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29) is for getting the value of numeric digits or symbols - so, for example, `Character.getNumericValue('7')` would return 7.  As `a` is a digit in hexadecimal, this method returns the hexadecimal value of `a`, or 10.

For the Unicode value of `a`, do `(int) 'a'` or `(int) "a".charAt(0)`. **

(** This doesn't work for Unicode characters in [astral planes](http://everything2.com/title/Astral+Plane), but these are rare.)

Answer (score 0):

You did not bother to [read the javaDoc for getNumericalValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28int%29), so I'll add the link, and tell you that the numerical value for both `A` and `a` are supposed to be 10.

Answer (score 0):

You could also you test it m8

```
public class Main {

private static final char low = 'a';
private static final char high = 'z';
private static final int arrayLength = high - low + 1;

    public static void main(String [ ] args) {

        System.out.println("a: "+Character.getNumericValue(low));
        System.out.println("z: "+Character.getNumericValue(high));
        System.out.println("The arrayLenght is: "+arrayLength);
   } 
}
```

Console output:

a: 10

z: 35

The arrayLenght is: 26

Answer (score 0):

```
Character.getNumericValue(char);
```

work like this 
**char** 0 to 9 return **int** 0 to 9
**char** a **(or)** A to z **(or)** Z return 10 to 35.
that mean **Alphanumeric**.
and unicode also include.
other char value return -1.

Comment: Not strictly true.  There are lots of weird and wonderful numeric symbols in Unicode - try `Character.getNumericValue('\u2472')`, for example...